# Calculating weighted averages in queries vba access

Tags: javascript, sql, ms-access, vba

I'm working on a database that needs to value WEIGHTED average cost for 
inventory based on actual costs per unit.  The source data 
is in a query that combines item receiving/return history, 
and sorts the results by item ID and by receipt date. 
So, what I get from this query looks like this:

ITEM #       RECPT_DATE    QTY    UNIT_COST 
 A1           10/15/2001    100         5.50 
 A1           09/02/2001     50         6.00 
 A1           06/10/2001     40         7.00 
 A2           12/02/2001     75        15.00 
 A2           07/20/2001     20        14.50

Now, I have another table that tells me the total on hand 
 quantities of each item in inventory.

ITEM #       TOT_QTY 
 A1               [WEIGHTED average cost ] 
 A2                [WEIGHTED average cost ]
So, is this possible to do with VBA in access? 
ANY help would be much appreciated!

Thx.

```
Public Function SumProduct(Array1 As Variant, Array2 As Variant) As Variant

    Dim lngRowMax As Long
    Dim lngColMax As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim var As Variant

    lngRowMax = IIf(UBound(Array1, 2) <= UBound(Array2, 2), UBound(Array1, 2), UBound(Array2, 2))
    lngColMax = IIf(UBound(Array1) <= UBound(Array2), UBound(Array1), UBound(Array2))
    ReDim var(0 To lngRowMax)
    For i = 0 To lngRowMax
        For j = 0 To lngColMax
            var(i) = var(i) + Array1(j, i) * Array2(j, i)
        Next j
        SumProduct = SumProduct + var(i)
    Next i

End Function
```

Comment: I try with SumProduct:

Comment: What is SumProduct?

Comment: a function in vba code

Answer (score 0):

Public Function SumProduct(Array1 As Variant, Array2 As Variant) As Variant

```
Dim lngRowMax As Long
Dim lngColMax As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim var As Variant

lngRowMax = IIf(UBound(Array1, 2) <= UBound(Array2, 2), UBound(Array1, 2), UBound(Array2, 2))
lngColMax = IIf(UBound(Array1) <= UBound(Array2), UBound(Array1), UBound(Array2))
ReDim var(0 To lngRowMax)
For i = 0 To lngRowMax
    For j = 0 To lngColMax
        var(i) = var(i) + Array1(j, i) * Array2(j, i)
    Next j
    SumProduct = SumProduct + var(i)
Next i
```

End Function